# How to find the direction in which the maxima of a changing array is moving in?

Tags: arrays, analysis

I have a dynamically updating array ,(changes every second). 
and it consists of values from 1 to 9 . I am given a task to find out whether the maximum values are moving from left to right or right to left .

For this input the output should be left to right .  The data is oncoming from a sensor and is updating the array every second .

```html
[1 , 3 , 4 , 2 , 1 , 0 , 0 ]
[1 , 1 , 4 , 8 , 4 , 0 , 0 ]
[1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 9 , 0 , 0 ]
[4 , 0 , 0 , 9 , 9 , 0 , 0 ]
[4 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 3 , 8 , 3 ]
[6 , 3 , 4 , 0 , 9 , 9 , 8 ]
```

the only way i can think of is to take the largest 3 elements in the array and sum and save their indices , if this number increases more than 2 times then we have left to right or if it decreases we have right to left movement .

Is there any other way to achieve this . 
If you're writing code , python would help .thanks .

Comment: Asking for code without writing any yourself is pretty audacious. Asking for it in a specific language will most likely get you downvoted. Just an FYI

Answer (score 0):

Average the indices of the maximums at each array, and then compare those averages.

You’ll have to define “moving left to right” in terms you can program, such as `index_average[x] < index_average[x+1] < index_average[x+2]`